# SQLAlchemy Why is insert().values 45 times slower than Table(values)?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In the two examples below, why is method #1, so much slower than method #2 (1m:30s vs ~2s)? Looking at the documentation, it *appears* that method #1 is the newer(?) method [[link to docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#the-insert-sql-expression-construct)], however, since the documentation itself says that it's combination of 1.x and 2.0 styles, I'm not sure.

I guess the problem lies with `session.execute()` being slower than using `session.add_all()` but is there another way?

I have tried variations of method #1, mainly using `with engine.connect() as conn:` and moving `session.commit()` to inside the loop but nothing really changes.

What am I misunderstanding?

```python
>>> len(testdata)
993
```

```python
#  Setup
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@database/db', future=True)
```

```python
#  Method 1
metadata = MetaData(engine)

customers = Table('customers', metadata,
                  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                  Column('email', String(255)),
                  Column('name', String(255)),
                  Column('currency', String(3)),
                  Column('next_invoice_sequence', Integer),
                  Column('metadata', JSON),
                  Column('customer_id', String(22)),
                  )

session = Session(engine)
for i in testdata:
    stmt = insert(customers).values(
        email=i['email'], name=i['name'], currency=i['currency'],
        next_invoice_sequence=i['next_invoice_sequence'],
        metadata=i['metadata'],
        customer_id=shortuuid.ShortUUID().uuid(i['email']),
        created=i['created'])
    session.execute(stmt)
session.commit()
```

```python
#  Method 2
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base

class Customers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255))
    name = Column(String(255))
    currency = Column(String(3))
    next_invoice_sequence = Column(Integer)
    metadata_ = Column("metadata", JSON)
    customer_id = Column(String(22))
    created = Column(BigInteger)

stmts = []
for i in testdata:
    stmt = Customers(
        email=i['email'], name=i['name'], currency=i['currency'],
        next_invoice_sequence=i['next_invoice_sequence'],
        metadata_=i['metadata'],
        customer_id=shortuuid.ShortUUID().uuid(i['email']),
        created=i['created'])

    stmts.append(stmt)

session = Session(engine)
session.add_all(stmts)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Log the SQL statements in the database and see if they are the problem.

Comment: also check if the slower version does commit after every statement (on `session.execute(stmt)`) whereas the orm version does this just once.

Comment: The slower version has `session.commit()` outside of the loop so it does it all at once.